# Where is my ffmpeg stream getting saved to?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, angstrom-linux

I'm just starting to explore ffmpeg (ultimately for use with openCV), and I'm running this command:

```
root@beaglebone:/# ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 /out.avi
```

At which point the camera indicator light turns on and it appears to be capturing. However when I end it with `CTRL+C`, the file is nowhere to be found.

Any thoughts?

Full output:

```
root@beaglebone:/# ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 /out.avi
ffmpeg version v0.7.4, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the Libav developers
  built on Oct  9 2012 10:50:57 with gcc 4.5.4 20120305 (prerelease)
  configuration: --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --cross-prefix=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi- --prefix=/usr --enable-ffserver --enable-ffplay --enable-x11grab --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --arch=arm --target-os=linux --enable-cross-compile --extra-cflags=' -fexpensive-optimizations -fomit-frame-pointer -O4 -ffast-math -march=armv7-a -fno-tree-vectorize -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8 --sysroot=/home/koen/setup-scripts/build/tmp-angstrom_v2012_05-eglibc/sysroots/beaglebone' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed' --sysroot=/home/koen/setup-scripts/build/tmp-angstrom_v2012_05-eglibc/sysroots/beaglebone --enable-hardcoded-tables --cpu=cortex-a8
  libavutil    51.  7. 0 / 51.  7. 0
  libavcodec   53.  6. 0 / 53.  6. 0
  libavformat  53.  3. 0 / 53.  3. 0
  libavdevice  53.  0. 0 / 53.  0. 0
  libavfilter   2.  4. 0 /  2.  4. 0
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  52.  0. 0 / 52.  0. 0
^C
root@beaglebone:/# ls
bin   dev  home  lost+found  mnt  proc  sbin  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media       opt  run   sys   usr
root@beaglebone:/#
```

Comment: The forward slash (`/`) indicates the [root directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory). Did you check the root directory for your file? The complete ffmpeg console output will be useful.

Comment: I did check (initially it was just going into my home directory, but I've been playing around a little bit). I've added my full output.

Comment: Perhaps try specifying a time limit for capture. '-t 1' should do one second. I'm thinking that the problem might be that the early Ctrl-C might be messing things up. Limiting the time to capture might give FFmpeg a chance to gracefully exit. Another idea would be to print CRCs of individual frames to stdout, rather than dumping frames to a file. Do this by replacing '/out.avi' with '-f framecrc -'.

Comment: Not a good idea to run ffmpeg as root.  Setup your security to allow group access to the video device if that's your problem.

Comment: @cmevoli, why is it not a good idea to run it as root (in comparison to doing anything else as root)

Comment: @Chris, if you make any small mistake or there is a bug in an application, you can mess up your machine.  It's just safer to do everything as a normal, restricted user unless you have to use root access.  It's a good practice and habit to get into.

Comment: @cmevoli. Understood... so no thoughts on why I can't find my file?

Answer (score 0):

Using `CTRL+C` you are forcing your application to quit immediately. Doing this your file is not finished yet by FFmpeg. Using your current settings FFmpeg will only finish your file when the input stream stops, since no output options are set. So, one solution is adding a time option like `-t 60` to your output file, where 60 is in seconds.

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -t 60 /out.avi
```

Another solution is stopping the input stream, like disconnecting/unmounting the camera. Then the stream stops and your file is written automatically. (not entirely true, because FFmpeg is actually writing each frame after each frame, but not finishing the file. Don't bother about that...)

Answer (score 0):

Fire following command

```
whereis ffmpeg
```